# Change array type: 8bit type to 6bit type

Tags: bit, ada

I have two types and two arrays of that types in file.ads

```
 type Ebit is mod 2**8;
 type Sbit is mod 2**6;
 type Data_Type is array (Positive range <>) of Ebit;
 type Changed_Data_Type is array (Positive range <>) of Sbit;
```

and function:

```
function ChangeDataType (D : in Data_Type) return Changed_Data_Type
 with
   Pre => D'Length rem 3 = 0 and D'Last < Positive'Last / 4,
 Post => ChangeDataType'Result'Length = 4 * (D'Length / 3)
```

Ok i can understand all of this.
For example we have arrays of:

65, 66, 65, 65, 66, 65 in 8bit values function should give to us 16, 20, 9, 1, 16, 20, 9, 1 in 6bit values.

I dont know how i can build a 6bit table from 8 bit table.

My idea of sollutions is for example taking bit by bit from type:

```
fill all bites in 6bit type to 0 (propably default)
if first bit (2**1) is 1 set bit (2**1) in 6bit type to 1;
and do some iterations
```

But i dont know how to do this, always is a problem with types. Is this good idea or i can do this with easier way? I spend last nigt to try write this but without success.

Edit:
I wrote some code, its working but i have problem with array initialization.

```
function ChangeDataType (D: in Data_Type) return Changed_Data_Type
 is
  length: Natural := (4*(D'Length / 3));
  ER: Changed_Data_type(length);
  Temp: Ebit;     
  Temp1: Ebit;
  Temp2: Ebit;
  Actual: Ebit;
  n: Natural;
  k: Natural;
begin
  n := 0;
  k := 0;
  Temp := 2#00000000#;
  Temp1 := 2#00000000#;
  Temp2 := 2#00000000#;

  Array_loop:
  for k in D'Range loop
     case n is
        when 0 =>
           Actual := D(k);
           Temp1 := Actual / 2**2;
           ER(k) := Sbit(Temp1);
           Temp := Actual * ( 2**4);
           n := 2; 
        when 2 =>
           Actual := D(k);
           Temp1 := Actual / 2**4;
           Temp2 := Temp1 or Temp;
           ER(k) := Sbit(Temp2);
           Temp := Actual * ( 2**2); 
           n := 4;
        when 4 =>
           Actual := D(k);
           Temp1 := Actual / 2**6;
           Temp2 := Temp1 or Temp;
           ER(k) := Sbit(Temp2);
           n := 6;
        when 6 =>
           Temp1 := Actual * ( 2**2);
           Temp2 := Actual / 2**2;
           ER(k) := Sbit(Temp2);
           n := 0;
        when others =>
           n := 0;
     end case;
  end loop Array_Loop;


  return ER;
 end;
```

Comment: `and`, `or`, `xor`, and `not` are the bitwise operations on modular types.  If you need a shift, you can multiply or divide by a power of 2.

Comment: Thx for reply. When i am trying to set 6bit value from 8bit with bitwise operator i always get "expected type 8bit" from ADA.
Can you give me one example how to set up 6bit value?

Comment: 2 mistakes in posted code :  `length: Natural := (4*((D'Length + 2) / 3));` surely, to avoid the off-by-1 error when Length mod 3 /= 0... and `ER: Changed_Data_type( 1 .. length);` i.e. a subtype_mark exactly as the error message says. Plus, if you get the packed array below to work, you eliminate that entire loop and case statement...

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. You have right, its work fine with 1..4 for example. In the test file to this quest i have (1 .. 4) too. Ok its time to sleep now, thanks for the help one more time ;) Edit: (1 .. length) good idea!

Comment: If `S` is an `Sbit` and `E` is an `Ebit`, then a type conversion, `S := SBit(E);`, will let you set a 6-bit value from an 8-bit value.  It will raise `Constraint_Error` if `E` is >= 64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF I understand what you're asking... it's that you want to re-pack the same 8-bit data into 6-bit values such that the "leftover" bits of the first `EBit` become the first bits (highest or lowest?) of the second `Sbit`.

One way you can do this - at least for fixed size arrays, e.g. your 6 words * 8 bits, 8 words * 6 bits example, is by specifying the exact layout in memory for each array type, using packing, and [representation aspects](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-1.html#I4839) (or pragmas, before Ada-2012) which are [nicely described here](http://www.adacore.com/uploads/technical-papers/Ada2012_Rationale_Chp1_contracts_and_aspects.pdf).

I haven't tested the following, but it may serve as a starting point.

```
 type Ebit is mod 2**8;
 type Sbit is mod 2**6;
 for Ebit'Size use 8;
 for Sbit'Size use 6;
 type Data_Type is array (1 .. 6) of Ebit
    with Alignment => 0;  -- this should pack tightly
 type Changed_Data_Type is array (1 .. 8) of Sbit
    with Alignment => 0;
```

Then you can instantiate the generic `Unchecked_Conversion` function with the two array types, and use that function to convert from one array to the other.

```
 with Ada.Unchecked_Conversion;
 function Change_Type is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion(Data_Type, Changed_Data_Type);

 declare
   Packed_Bytes : Changed_Data_Type := Change_Type(Original_Bytes);
 begin ...
```

In terms of code generated, it's not slow, because Unchecked_Conversion doesn't do anything, except tell the compile-time type checking to look the other way.

I view `Unchecked_Conversion` like the "I meant to do that" look my cat gives me after falling off the windowledge. Again...

Alternatively, if you wish to avoid copying, you can declare Original_Bytes as aliased, and use a similar trick with access types and `Unchecked_Access` to overlay both arrays on the same memory (like a Union in C). I think this is what DarkestKhan calls "array overlays" in a comment below. See also section 3 of [this rather dated page](http://www.adahome.com/articles/1997-06/am_cando.html) which describes the technique further. It notes the overlaid variable must not only be declared `aliased` but also `volatile` so that accesses to one view aren't optimised into registers, but reflect any changes made via the other view. Another approach to overlays is in the [Ada Wikibook here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Type_System#Overlays).

Now this may be vulnerable to endian-ness considerations, i.e. it may work on some platforms but not others. The second reference above gives an example of a record with exact bit-alignment of its members : we can at least take the `Bit_Order` aspect, as in `with Alignment => 0, Bit_Order => Low_Order_First;` for the arrays above...

```
-- code stolen from "Rationale" ... see link above p.11
type RR is record
      Code: Opcode;
      R1: Register;
      R2: Register;
end record
with Alignment => 2, Bit_Order => High_Order_First;

for RR use record
      Code at 0 range 0 .. 7;
      R1 at 1 range 0 .. 3;
      R2 at 1 range 4 .. 7;
end record;
```

One thing that's not clear to me is if there's a formulaic way to specify the exact layout of each element in an array, as is done in a record here - or even if there's a potential need to. If necessary, one workaround would be to replace the arrays above with records. But I'd love to see a better answer if there is one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brian. I readed a lot about that. No sleep but i wrote some code ;) I am using or bitwise operation now, i will post my code after 8pm.

Comment: I have one more question: How i can assign Changed_Data_Type array with expression on range argument? I need create array with 4 * (D'Length / 3),Invalid index constraint on ER: Encoded_Data_Type(4*(D'Length / 3)); and Expect subtype mask for index constraint on       length: Natural := (4*(D'Length / 3));
      ER: Encoded_Data_Type(length);

Comment: I think, if this approach works, it's a helluva lot less low-level coding. Crypto may be different, but in embedded programming you see the C coders doing a lot of shifts,  masks, and bitwise manipulation instead of `Ctrl_Reg.Enable_Bit := True;`

Comment: I can't answer your OMQ, sorry, I haven't thought enough about extending this to variable length arrays. But I'd guess you have trouble with 4*D'Length/3 thanks to rounding and remainders.

Comment: Yes, i am using SPARK_Mode. Thanks for the BIG answer! I posted my code in first post ;) Yee problem is with 4*D'Length/3

Comment: One could also make use of array overlays... (iirc Unchecked_Conversion checks only one thing - that 'Size of both 'objects' agrees)

Comment: @darkestkhan : might be useful to expand on that in an answer, or provide a reference.